# How can I use bootstrap javascript library without accessing Internet and local file system?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, soti

I am developing a web page with the javascript bootstrap library for UI and layout design. It will run off an Android tablet.

It may work in an offiline environment and it cannot access the local file system. It means `<script src='{Url to js file}'></script>` won't work.

How can it access the bootstrap css and js files? Can then be included as inline codes in the html?

Comment: you can simply copy the content of files to your js/css file and put this file in your project folder and link them

Comment: or download this files and put it in your project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS can be included in following ways in an HTML

- Using CDN (Internet)
- Using local file system(external stylesheets)
- using internal stylesheets (`<style>`)
- Placing Inline styles

Considering the above, you have only one case left, i.e. include all styles in  tag and make it work. You may apply checks that internal stylesheets should work only when it's offline mode.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use local file:**

you have tow ways to do it:

1. download the files and put them in your project folder and creat `links/script` to those files:

`<script src="folderInProject/bootstrap.js"></script>`

2. the links below contain the code :

   `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`

simply go to the url and copy the code inside to your local `js/css` files:

for example go to this link and copy the code:

https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css